# Is it better to go to my shop steward or to my supervisor

Tags: united-states, unions

There's a new problem with some equipment. Since OSHA visited the plant last year we got some stuff fixed, but now we got new safety equipment and rules we have to follow that make things worse. So like we have to wear two gloves instead of one when handling hot things. But now I burned myself and my supervisor wrote a report and is thinking of giving me a safety write up.
I was wearing both gloves but the cooling area is closed and has to be opened and my hand slipped because we used to just open the door with our free hand and hold the tray in your other and we didn't have the glove on that hand. Now my hand slipped on the door handle, and I got burned by the tray when I tried to catch myself and I'm worried because I think they know that I called OSHA last year and they're going to use this an excuse.

So I'm not too sure if I should got to the union and fight the write up or to talk to my supervisor and tell him so I won't get written up, but I'm not sure because if you go to management the union doesn't do anything because you have to go with a rep from the start if you want them to represent you. So if anyone knows who I should go see that would be great.

**Question:** Who should I go see about my issue?

Comment: I've never been part of a union, but in general the union is more on your side than management is.

Comment: Do you have reason to think that going to your union rep would be a mistake?  Can you go to your union rep just to ask for advice?

Comment: Do you think the accident happened directly *because* of the new safety rules? (wearing two gloves? I'm not a safety expert or anything, but wearing one glove inside another doesn't sound like a great solution to me...) Who created the rules? And to clarify.. you believe OSHA visited because of your call last year?

Comment: What country is this?  What sort of employment protection is there for union members?

Comment: Added United-States tag as OSHA is part of the US Government Dept of Labor

Comment: I don't remember exactly, but I'm pretty sure that OSHA helps with any kind of retaliation from the company if an employee calls.

Answer (score 10):

> So I'm not too sure if I should got tot he union and fight the wrtite
>   up or to talk to my supervisor and tell him so I wont get written up
>   but I'm not sure because if yo go to management the union doesn't do
>   antthing because you gotta go with a rep from the start if you want
>   them to represent tyou so if anyone knows hwo I shoulde go see that
>   would be grate.

Talk with your union rep immediately.

Explain what happened and why. Follow their advice closely.

You rep might talk to your supervisor on your behalf, or might suggest that you talk with your supervisor yourself. Either way you are on record and will get the help you might need from your union.

Comment: I'll add a word of warning: only do this if you have a competent union.  An incompetent union riddled with corruption can make things worse (I've seen it happen).